# Is there other media belong to the Sono Hanabira series besides the Visual Novels

Tags: sono-hanabira

I know of the following

- 12 Visual Novels featuring the couples from the Saint Michael’s School for Girls
- 1 Visual Novel set in a nursing school with a different couple
- An All Ages visual Novel (Hanahira!) which focuses on the juniors of Saint Michael’s
- An OVA which is an adaptation of the 3rd Visual Novel with Reo and Mai (Difference is that Reo gets sick and Mai visits her rather than the other way around, then Mai gets sick after catching it from Reo)

Now a while back when i was looking where to get the Visual Novels i saw an image of a manga and it had Yuuna Matsubara in it but i wasn't sure if it was fan made or an official manga (i don't have the image on me, i didn't download it but i think i saw it in with Petals' Garden or Yuri Project), so i am wondering what other media belong to the Sono Hanabira series aside from the Visual Novels (and the OVA i listed)?

Please note anything which may be NSFW (Not Safe For Work)

Comment: I think that's it, but I have no sources to back it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illustrator Peko, along with the other staffs who created the visual novels, published several [dojinshis (not safe for work)](http://lumino.sakura.ne.jp/doujin.html) that contained novels and illustrations (one copy of which I have). These might be considered official adaptation. Note that the visual novels themselves used to be distributed much like dojinshis (e.g., at comiket), and not like typical commercial VNs.

Comment: with the dojinshis, can they be purchased or just downloaded

Comment: @Memor-X I don't have any particular information about these dojinshis, but usual means of obtaining ones may apply.  Some of them are a bit old and may be hard to obtain.